# Python: separating columns and doing calculations within the data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Python beginner so please bear with me.

I have a file with 4 columns and ~1500 rows. What I need to do is return the following information to the console:

1) the gender, years, and wage for the highest earner

2) the gender, years, and wage for the lowest earner

3) the number of females in the top ten earners in this data set.

My data looks somewhat like this(in a csv file):

```
Gender, Years, Education, Wage
Female, 4, 9, 8.35
Male, 6, 6, 7.86 
Male, 2, 8, 6.95
Female, 5, 6, 7.45  
Male, 13, 9, 9.56
```

etc.

I've been told that pandas or numpy would be best suited for this type of work but I'm confused on the format for how I would do these types of problems.

Answer (score 3):

For the min and max, @Zero covers it well.  I'll contribute these thoughts:

- You can do it in one go using `agg`

  ```
  df.Wage.agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin'])

  idxmax    4
  idxmin    2
  Name: Wage, dtype: int64
  ```
- You can show just those rows with

  ```
  df.loc[df.Wage.agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin'])]

    Gender  Years  Education  Wage
  4   Male     13          9  9.56
  2   Male      2          8  6.95
  ```
- You can `join` it back with in order to get nifty index values telling you which is min and max

  ```
  df.Wage.agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin']).to_frame('index').join(df, on='index')

          index Gender  Years  Education  Wage
  idxmax      4   Male     13          9  9.56
  idxmin      2   Male      2          8  6.95
  ```

---

For the count of females among top earners, I'd use `pd.DataFrame.nlargest` where we pass not only the number for `n` but the column we are to use for determining largest.

```
df.nlargest(10, 'Wage').Gender.eq('Female').sum()

2
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Highest Earner

```
In [4336]: df.loc[df['Wage'].idxmax()]
Out[4336]:
Gender       Male
Years          13
Education       9
Wage         9.56
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

2) Lowest Earner

```
In [4337]: df.loc[df['Wage'].idxmin()]
Out[4337]:
Gender       Male
Years           2
Education       8
Wage         6.95
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

3) Number of females in top 10 earners

```
In [4338]: df[df['Wage'] >= df['Wage'].nlargest(10).iloc[-1]]['Gender'].eq('Female').sum()
Out[4338]: 2
```

---

Details

You would read the csv into dataframe like `df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`

```
In [4339]: df
Out[4339]:
   Gender  Years  Education  Wage
0  Female      4          9  8.35
1    Male      6          6  7.86
2    Male      2          8  6.95
3  Female      5          6  7.45
4    Male     13          9  9.56
```

Comment: This is pandonic way :)

Comment: Good answer worthy of my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')

df.sort_values('Wage', ascending=False, inplace=True)

highest_earner = df.iloc[0]
lowest_earner = df.iloc[-1]

num_of_females = len(df.iloc[0:10][df['Gender'] == 'Female'])
```